# php5 curl: Recompiling does not reflect in phpinfo

Tags: php, linux, apache, curl, configuration

I am trying to get curl to work on my Oracle Linux OS, but I am running into some walls.  I am loading my phpinfo() page using an Apache + Django combined server.  Furthermore, I have made sure to uncomment the `extension=php_curl.dll` line in the `php.ini` file, and I have added the `extension=curl.so` line.  I have also attempted to compile php again using `./configure --with-curl=/usr/include/curl/`, followed by the `make` and `sudo make install` method calls.  However, this recompiling is not reflecting in the phpinfo() page, which still shows a later build date and a different configuration command.  As an added note, I am pretty sure I have curl installed.  I've run `sudo yum install php-curl` and `sudo yum install curl`, and both have responded to me, saying that the `php-common` and `curl` packages, respectively, have already been installed.

Does anyone have any advice?  Thanks.

Comment: have you added `extension=curl.so` to your php.ini?

Comment: I just tried adding that underneath the `extension=php_curl.dll` line, and the results were fruitless.  :(

Comment: where have you placed the curl.dll?

Comment: All of it is in my php.ini file.  I placed the `curl.so` and `php_curl.dll` with the rest of the extensions, under the Dynamic Extensions labeled part.

Comment: enable `display_startup_errors` in php.ini. what does it say?

Comment: It has always been 'On'.  Where would the errors be displayed?

Comment: in terminal or browser. depends on how you execute the php script

Comment: No errors are showing up in the terminal or browser.  I execute the script via the phpinfo() method that is stuck into the php file.  I open it through Apache + Django server, and it shows up fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the solution was to install **libcurl** & **libcurl-devel**.